# Getting Performance Results using benchmarkdotnet in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, benchmarkdotnet

I am testing benchmark library to measure the performance of the code. I am reading up the documentation.

I am not able to figure out how to print out  results of benchmarks.
I have a class called user and i want to bechmark the following method.

```
[Benchmark]
public bool FollowerAdded(User newFollower)
{
    // code for notifying user that they have an added follower
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    return notification.NotifyUser(this, newFollower.UserName + " is now following you!");
}
```

In the documentation of benchmarkdot net, Use the following code to get printout  of bechmarks.

```
var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<User>();
```

Where can we put this code to get the results in case of Asp.net MVC application to get the benchmarking results?

here is the URL of the library
http://benchmarkdotnet.org/GettingStarted.htm

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but here it goes,

Probably you need a console application project to reference your library and run the benchmark, after running it the results will be printed on the console and the reports will be located in

```
summary.ResultsDirectoryPath
```

typically

```
$(TargetDir)BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\
```